# ServiceStack razor default page

Tags: c#, servicestack

Say I have 2 pages

1. `/NotADefault.cshtml`
2. `/Views/Default.cshtml`

**Question 1.**

Now I run it, page `A` always gets called implicitly as start-up default page no matter what I name it.

Page `B` will only be called when I explicitly call localhost/View/Default. How do I make page `B` (the one in View folder) my default page?

**Question 2.**

I also have `NotADefaultService.cs` and `DefaultService.cs`. I give each page a Service class at the back. However, when page `A` is called `NotADefaultService.cs` never gets called. Only `DefaultService.cs` gets called when page `B` is called...

My observation is that only the pages in the `View` folder will get their back-end service class working. Outside of `View` folder it doesn't work.

**Combining Q1 and Q2.**

How do I:

**Option 1.** get the backend service class working under `/ root` outside "View" folder?

OR

**Option 2.** appoint `/View/Default.schtml` as my default at start-up where the service class can be hit?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/):

- Razor Pages that exist within the `/Views/` folder are called **View Pages**
- Razor Pages that exist anywhere else are called **Content Pages**

The difference between them is that **View Pages** are Razor views that are used to provide the HTML representations (aka views) **for services** in much the same way View Pages work for MVC Controllers.

View Pages **cannot** be called directly, that's the role of **Content Pages**, which **can only** be called directly, i.e. outside the context of a service (or redirected to, from a service).

In [Razor Rockstars](http://razor.servicestack.net/), examples of Content Pages include:

- [/stars/dead/cobain/](http://razor.servicestack.net/stars/dead/cobain/) which calls the [/stars/dead/Cobain/default.cshtml](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost/stars/dead/Cobain/default.cshtml) Content Page
- [/TypedModelNoController](http://razor.servicestack.net/TypedModelNoController) which calls the [/TypedModelNoController.cshtml](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost/TypedModelNoController.cshtml) Content Page

Whereas examples of **View Pages** include:

- [/rockstars](http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars) which matches the `/rockstars` route on the [/RockstarsService.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost/RockstarsService.cs) and because of the `[DefaultView("Rockstars")]` attribute, uses the [/Rockstars.cshtml](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/blob/master/src/RazorRockstars.WebHost/Views/Rockstars.cshtml) **View Page**

### Default Pages

For **Content Pages** the `default.cshtml` is the index page for a folder. So to set a default page for the root `/` path, create a `/default.cshtml` page. An example of this is [/default.cshtml](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/Reusability/default.cshtml) home page used in the [Reusability](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/Reusability) demo.

If you want to use a view page as the Home page, you can set the default redirect to it by adding the AppHost config:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
   DefaultRedirectPath = "/home"
});
```

Which would call a **service** matching the `/home` route that will use the most appropriate View Page based on the rules laid out in the [Razor Rockstars](http://razor.servicestack.net/) page.

Comment: When using DefaultRedirectPath is there anything that can be done to not show /home in the address?

Comment: Nope, it only redirects. You'd need a to impl handle the default request in custom RawHttpHandler or a catch-all to provide a dynamic request for a default route. See [Order of Operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) for details about the custom hooks available.

Comment: Does this mean that ServiceStack.Razor doesn't follow the MVC pattern (except for View Pages to a certain extent)?

Comment: Not except, Your service (the Controller) returns the response (the Model) for Razor pages (the View) in `/Views` directory. Pages outside  (i.e. Content Pages) are called directly and do not go through a service. This is essentially what this answer is all about.

Comment: <urlMappings enabled="true"><add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/Home"/></urlMappings> Hides the /home

Comment: I found Jon Canning's answer along with using DefaultRedirectPath the most helpful. Maybe this can be mentioned in the ServiceStack documentation as well.

Comment: Îs this `DefaultPageName` now?