# Servicestack errors building view page

Tags: c#, razor, servicestack, razor-2

Im using Servicestack 3.9.59 with Servicestack.Razor as a standalone console program.

My Request/Response/Service looks like:

```
namespace Info
{
    [Route("/OverView")]
    public class OverViewRequest : IReturn<OverViewResponse>
    {}
    public class OverViewResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class OverViewService : Service
    {
        public OverViewResponse Get(OverViewRequest request)
        {
            return new OverViewResponse() { Name = "test" };
        }
    }
}
```

The view page looks like:

```
@inherits ViewPage<OverViewResponse>

@Model.Name
```

With a _Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="/static/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

And my apphost is configured as such:

```
namespace Info
{
class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
        public AppHost() : base("Server Info", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
            Config.DefaultRedirectPath = "/OverView";
            Config.DebugMode = true;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start("http://*:2001/");

            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

}
}
```

I tried my best to match the examples on RazorRockstars
However when I run the program I get the following output on the console:

```
at ServiceStack.Razor.Managers.RazorViewManager.TrackPage(IVirtualFile file)
at ServiceStack.Common.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[
    T
](IEnumerable`1 values,
Action`1 action)
at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.Init()
at ServiceStack.Razor.RazorFormat.Register(IAppHost appHost)
```

And visiting the page in my browser just shows the Snapshot of OverViewRequest generated by ServiceStack page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also need to add `[DefaultView("OverView")]`. This can be added above your service or above an individual method on your service so for example:

```
[DefaultView("OverView")]
public class OverViewService : Service
{
    public OverViewResponse Get(OverViewRequest request)
    {
        return new OverViewResponse() { Name = "test" };
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class OverViewService : Service
{
    [DefaultView("OverView")]
    public OverViewResponse Get(OverViewRequest request)
    {
        return new OverViewResponse() { Name = "test" };
    }
}
```

Then you need to add the `OverView.cshtml` file into a `Views` folder. See this answer for more info: [ServiceStack razor default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206038/servicestack-razor-default-page/13206221#13206221)

Comment: I have already tried that, and it doesnt change the outcome.
Could this have anything to do with the _Layout.cshtml file? Am I right in assuming its location should be just within the Views folder?

Comment: Yeah having the _Layout.cshtml file in the Views folder is correct