# ServiceStack Razor Views from Multiple Module Directories

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I am starting a new project in which the idea is to organize the project file/folder structure in to different modules (.csproj) and finally once deployed these modules would be loaded to one AppHost of MainModule (these sub modules would act as plugins).

However, for better physical file management (SVN/VCS) and effective organization of my project files these modules would be maintained as separate projects in SVN too. **Thought is to have views, assets etc. specific to each module in its own module directory scope.** [(Refer screenshot)](http://i.imgsafe.org/d6e849d.png).

- Main Module

  - SubModuleOne

    - Views

      - ModuleOneDefault.cshtml
  - SubModuleTwo

    - Views

      - ModuleTwoDefault.cshtml
  - Views

    - Shared

      - _Layout.cshtml
    - Hello.cshtml

Module specific files would be copied as post build action into root project path rather than /Views directly (if copied then it messes up with Main module's Views folder).

Problem is with how ServiceStack loads and handles Razor views from /Views folder and anything outside is considered to be content pages. [More about this, explained here...!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206038)

With [VirtualFileSystem](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system) in place I was thinking aloud to maintain module specific views in respective "/ModuleOne/Views/" folder but outside the root "/Views". Somehow, this doesn't seem to work, trying to seek help on how this could be achieved or handled appropriately.

PS: Am aware that anything outside Views folder is content pages, however the idea is still to maintain as Views folder but in different hierarchy - Hoping that ServiceStack Razor feature anyway handles nested (DEEP) structure well but within root /Views folder and not from the entire Project Root folder i.e. "/".

Question is, can this be achieved as is by default without any heavy lifting? or Should I be having custom VirtualPathProvider implementation etc.?

Opinion and thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Razor Views must be in the `/Views` folder but otherwise they can be any hierarchy as any levels of nesting doesn't affect how they're resolved, they just need to be uniquely named, e.g:

```
/Views
   /SubModuleOne
        ModuleOneDefault.cshtml
   /SubModuleTwo
        ModuleTwoDefault.cshtml
   /Shared
       _Layout.cshtml
```

Comment: Thanks @mythz , will proceed as suggested however as a future feature am assuming it'll be helpful to scan entire root recursive to consolidate views folders (of course keeping the naming consistent as "views" ) to make one grand virtual `/Views` folder. Not sure if this is feasible but just a wish.